# ASN.1 & OPTIONAL

Tags: asn.1

From what I understood, ASN.1 UPER encoding packs the encoded data as efficient as possible.

Using [asn1scc](https://github.com/ttsiodras/asn1scc) I compiled this into c-code:

```
HelloWorld DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN
    DataItems ::= SEQUENCE (SIZE (0..1024)) OF DataItem

    DataItem ::= SEQUENCE {
        name IA5String (SIZE (0..32)) OPTIONAL,
        address IA5String (SIZE (0..256)) OPTIONAL
    }

END
```

I thought that making a field OPTIONAL it would only consume the full space when it was enabled or else only 1 bit. Also if I would have a DataItems sequence of only 3 items, then that it would use less space than the full 1024 items.
Instead, instantiating the example above uses 260226 bytes!

Is there a way using ASN.1 to create smaller outputs?

Comment: Are you really looking at the size of the UPER encoding? The UPER encoding will reach that kind of size only if you include the maximum permitted number of DataItems, each of them containing a name and an address of the maximum permitted length.

Comment: I looked at the size of the bit"stream" after encoding. I did that by letting the asn1scc compiler emit use-cases and then replacing 1024 by 512. I would expect around 130113 bytes but still got test-files of 260226 bytes.

Comment: I confirm what I said above. UPER does not produce a bit stream of that size if you include shorter strings or fewer elements. I am not familiar with asn1scc so I can't comment about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that your specification is not valid ... you must add AUTOMATIC TAGS

```
HelloWorld DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS ::= BEGIN
    DataItems ::= SEQUENCE (SIZE (0..1024)) OF DataItem

    DataItem ::= SEQUENCE {
        name IA5String (SIZE (0..32)) OPTIONAL,
        address IA5String (SIZE (0..256)) OPTIONAL
    }

END
```

The reason is you cannot tell the difference between `name` and `address` when you decode (as they are both optional).

As for your question, the resource I use to get a quick answer is https://asn1.io/asn1playground/

A few examples:

```
value DataItems ::= {
{ name "one" },
{ name "two" },
{ name "three" }
}  
-- Encoded successfully in 14 bytes:
-- 00707BF7 6583E9DF 7C2F4D1C B2E5

value DataItems ::= {
{ name "one", address "one" },
{ name "two", address "two" },
{ name "three", address "three" }
}
-- Encoded successfully in 27 bytes:
-- 00787BF7 6501EFDD 970FA77D E03E9DF7 E2F4D1CB 2E502F4D 1CB2E5
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your example with `asn1scc` and it does produce the correct encoding - the same as produced by the ASN.1 Playground from OSS.

The problem probably came from the way you read the size of the buffer.

You have to call `BitStream_GetLength(&bitstr)` to get the size of the encoded data. Instead you perhaps looked at the `.count` field in the bitstream? This is initialized to the maximum size of the buffer, which in that case is indeed 260226.